# _crypto is not defined

Tags: webpack, browser-sync, cryptojs

I've been digging on this for about an hour, but can't figure out what's causing the issue. I'm using webpack, browser-sync, and react with react-redux. Here's the error from the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _crypto is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:881), <anonymous>:5:11)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:881), <anonymous>:20:3)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:881), <anonymous>:21:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:881)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:875), <anonymous>:3:11)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:875), <anonymous>:46:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:875)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:833), <anonymous>:4:14)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just encountered this too. The solution for me was to upgrade the crypto-browserify dependency:

```
npm install crypto-browserify@3.11.0
```

**EDIT 1**: For reasons I don't quite grasp, this only fixed the problem temporarily. As soon as I restarted webpack, it stopped working again.

**EDIT 2**: This happens only in one of my projects, which is rather complex, so it's hard to pin down exactly what the differences are between the two, but as a temporary fix, you can just declare the variable:

```
window._crypto = null;
```

It's not pretty, but hopefully this will be temporary.

Comment: Thanks. I've been going into crypto-browserify and adding `var` to the beginning of the 3rd line of rng.js. I opened an issue on the crypto-browserify github about this, hopefully it will be addressed soon.

Answer (score 0):

that is a super out of date version of crypto browserify, rng.js has been gone since at least 3.9.8 which was released almost a year ago, something is requiring an out of date version.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, and found the reason.

As you use webpack 1.x, the `node-libs-browser@7.0` with `crypto-browserify@3.3.0` (maybe earlier) will be installed at the same time.

So, if you just `require('crypto')` directly, webpack will use the `@3.3.0`, which has the `rng.js`, and not the newest version you installed by yourself.

[image]

The solution I tried is just `npm install node-libs-browser --save`, and npm will update it in webpack, and @3.11.0 will be found.